# How to assign data from API response to state?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am retrieving the data from API. But I can't assign that object to the state object in vuex.

HERE IS MY STATE OBJECT

```
 state: {
    calendarOptions:[],
}
```

how will I assign data to calendarOptions by api call?

And in My Action

```
actions: {
//some api call, and its response 

this.state.calendarOptions = response.data

}
```

i need something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in docs of [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions) explained how to do that
for changing state you have to use mutations

### Example

```js
export default {
    state: {
        calendarOptions:[],
    },
    mutations: {
        setCalendarOptions(state, data) {
            state.calendarOptions = data
        }
    },
    actions: {
       getCalendarOption({commit}) {
           //some api call, and its response 

           commit("setCalendarOptions", response.data)
       }
    }
}
```